# phpMyAdmin and big tables

Tags: phpmyadmin

Trying to access to database with big tables (at least 15 tables in this database not less then 1 million, maximum - 20 million). Once I select database - phpMyAdmin loading at least 5 minutes (and more).

How can I speed-up load of page with tables?

Comment: Are you sorting the tables? Do you have any indicies or primary keys? What storage engine are you using?

Comment: My guess is a ton of slow count statements.

Comment: Using InnoDB for all. I'm just open database home page. 1st step - login. 2nd - choose database.... 3rd wait minutes and minutes...

Answer (score 10):

Paste these lines into the bottom of your config.inc.php file within your phpMyAdmin installation:

```
//http://future500.nl/phpmyadmin-slow-on-startup/:
$cfg['MaxExactCountViews'] = 0;//disable trying to count the number of rows in any view
$cfg['MaxExactCount'] = 0;//disable correcting the InnoDB estimates
```

Thank you to future500.nl!

I wish I'd found this fix hours earlier, before I accidentally deleted all my data.  :-(

Comment: If you are monitoring multiple servers with phpmyadmin, note that this is global variable.  I tried $cfg['Servers'][$i]['MaxExactCountViews'] = 0; and could not get it working.  Only later did I clue in that I cannot set this value per server.  Hope this helps others.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe we can hunt this down together with others interested?

I marked the columns in the `intormation_schema.tables` that are slow to be accessed:

```
SELECT 

`TABLE_CATALOG`
,`TABLE_SCHEMA`
,`TABLE_NAME`
,`TABLE_TYPE`
,`ENGINE`
,`VERSION`
,`ROW_FORMAT`      ------SLOW
,`TABLE_ROWS`      ------SLOW
,`AVG_ROW_LENGTH`  ------SLOW
,`DATA_LENGTH`     ------SLOW
,`MAX_DATA_LENGTH` ------SLOW
,`INDEX_LENGTH`    ------SLOW
,`DATA_FREE`       ------SLOW
,`AUTO_INCREMENT`  ------SLOW
,`CREATE_TIME`     ------SLOW
,`UPDATE_TIME`     ------SLOW
,`CHECK_TIME`      ------SLOW
,`TABLE_COLLATION`
,`CHECKSUM`        ------SLOW
,`CREATE_OPTIONS`
,`TABLE_COMMENT`

 FROM `tables` WHERE 1
```

Also, the navigation frame is the `/navigation.php` which calls

`/libraries/common.lib.php  => PMA_getTableList()` which then calls

`/libraries/database_interface.lib.php  => PMA_DBI_get_tables_full()`

which contains one of the slow queries.

I replaced the slow SELECT columns in this:

```
SELECT *,
`TABLE_SCHEMA`       AS `Db`,
`TABLE_NAME`         AS `Name`,
`TABLE_TYPE`         ÀS `TABLE_TYPE`,
`ENGINE`             AS `Engine`,
`ENGINE`             AS `Type`,
`VERSION`            AS `Version`,
`ROW_FORMAT`         AS `Row_format`,
`TABLE_ROWS`         AS `Rows`,
`AVG_ROW_LENGTH`     AS `Avg_row_length`,
`DATA_LENGTH`        AS `Data_length`,
`MAX_DATA_LENGTH`    AS `Max_data_length`,
`INDEX_LENGTH`       AS `Index_length`,
`DATA_FREE`          AS `Data_free`,
`AUTO_INCREMENT`     AS `Auto_increment`,
`CREATE_TIME`        AS `Create_time`,
`UPDATE_TIME`        AS `Update_time`,
`CHECK_TIME`         AS `Check_time`,
`TABLE_COLLATION`    AS `Collation`,
`CHECKSUM`           AS `Checksum`,
`CREATE_OPTIONS`     AS `Create_options`,
`TABLE_COMMENT`      AS `Comment`
```

To this:

```
SELECT 
`TABLE_SCHEMA`        AS `Db`,
`TABLE_NAME`          AS `Name`,
`TABLE_TYPE`          AS `TABLE_TYPE`,
`ENGINE`              AS `Engine`,
`ENGINE`              AS `Type`,
`VERSION`             AS `Version`,
'Compact'             AS `Row_format`,
0                     AS `Rows`,
0                     AS `Avg_row_length`,
0                     AS `Data_length`,
0                     AS `Max_data_length`,
0                     AS `Index_length`,
0                     AS `Data_free`,
0                     AS `Auto_increment`,
'2000-01-01 00:00:00' AS `Create_time`,
NULL                  AS `Update_time`,
NULL                  AS `Check_time`,
`TABLE_COLLATION`     AS `Collation`,
NULL                  AS `Checksum`,
`CREATE_OPTIONS`      AS `Create_options`,
`TABLE_COMMENT`       AS `Comment`
```

Which made the query run fast. (I usually don't need the Row count for example.. And I can get them manually as well. Or have 2 PhpMyAdmin installs.)

Note: the overridden values should appear as dummy values from now on on the admin page - but I could live with that rather then the slow speed.

But there must be other slow queries well, as it still loads slowly.

So, just wanted to share this, someone may go on with it. Right now, I have no more time.

Answer (score -3):

phpMyAdmin is browser based webpage tool. Why don't you try some other tools to work on database like [sqlyog](http://www.webyog.com/en/).

Comment: I have such limitation. My ISP rejecting 3306 traffic. So only way - is web based.

Comment: phpMyAdmin will behave slow with this kind of heavy load because when you use its GUI to see the structure or browse data or table listing it fire queries on mysql console as per you need .. Else way is to use console directly.. or you can try to connect sqlyog with the port you are using mysql console, if you can do with phpMyAdmin it can also be done by sqlyog or any other tool.

Comment: I'm using [dbForge](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/) but no chances with my ISP use it - becase such products connecting to database directly through 3306 port. So I was wundering if phpmyadmin has some options to speed up loading of big tables info.

Comment: if you are using old version of phpMyadmin, you can update it to latest one or you can choose a basic classic theme so that phpMyAdmin will not waste time to create attractive look and feel for display.

Comment: I think main point is in scanning tables (size, rows, etc). If I could deactivate this option...